# Trying to clean out winsxs using DISM, getting an error

Tags: windows-7, winsxs

I am running out of space on my 64GB SSD drive, and winsxs is largely to blame. 
Here's a screenshot of the problem
[image]
Also, notice that CBS.log file (but that's a problem for another day)

As you can see, I have the latest updates installed, and yet "Windows Update Cleanup" is only offering to remove a measly 32MB.

So next, I tried running the following command `DISM /online /cleanup-Image /spsuperseded` but got this output

```
C:\Windows\system32>DISM /online /cleanup-Image /spsuperseded

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385


Error: 183

The specified image is currently being serviced by another DISM operation.
Wait for the existing DISM operation to complete, and then try the operation again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

I would appreciate any help. This has been bugging me for months now.

Comment: You have looked in the log file to determine what operation is pending?  Of course my question is what makes you believe the WinSxS folder can be safely be made smaller then it already is?

Comment: You have already removed the backup files for Service Pack 1.  This means you have already basically ran the command you are trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Disk Cleanup tool (shown in your screenshot) uses DISM in the background.  If it's scanning, or was recently used to scan, or making changes, etc. it can cause other DISM instances to display that error.

Close all instances of the Disk Cleanup tool and try the DISM command again.

Comment: PS: see here regarding you CBS.Log file: [Why is CBS.log file size 20 GB](http://superuser.com/questions/803842/why-is-cbs-log-file-size-20-gb)

Answer (score -1):

you are getting that error because you are running the program that is checking the file sizes and it is locking the computer out from using the DISM service. It should tell you that in the log file.