# How to generate a cbs.log file in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, error-logging

This is a follow up question to [Windows 7 Update Failed on Multiple attempts](https://superuser.com/questions/1322413/windows-7-update-failed-on-multiple-attempts) where I am having issues trying to install windows 7 monthly security roll up. Below is the error.

[image: Windows Install Error]

The problem might similar to [Strange Windows 7 Security Monthly Quality Rollup Update failure](https://superuser.com/questions/1253315/strange-windows-7-security-monthly-quality-rollup-update-failure?rq=1). As part of root cause analysis, above question author has created *cbs error log* file.

**Question**: How do you create a cbs error log files?

References:

- [Component-Based Servicing (cbs.log) causes all drive space to be consumed](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7/solved-component-based-servicing-cbslog-causes-all/0b91bea0-31b5-42a1-8293-e9040c4eedfa)
- [Restrict Windows CBS.log verbosity, set log level, stop hectomegabyte info madness](https://superuser.com/questions/981727/restrict-windows-cbs-log-verbosity-set-log-level-stop-hectomegabyte-info-madne)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. The **CBS.log** file is generated automatically by the Windows Installer Module service.

You will find the log at:

```
C:\Windows\System\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
```

The most recent events will be found in the file named CBS.log. Each time the Windows Modules Installer service is started (e.g. at system startup) the current CBS.log file is compressed in a `CbsPersist_<timestamp>.cab` file. These archives are saved in the same folder.

Note that other functions such as System Restore also write events to the CBS log file.

---

*Interesting side note:*  Sometimes the CBS.log archive process fails when Windows attempts to compress it but runs into the [2 GB CAB file size limit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_installer_team/2005/09/18/what-are-the-upper-limits-of-the-cab-file-format/). If this happens, it can lead to [exhaustion of all free space](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3112358/microsoft-windows/windows-7-log-file-compression-bug-can-fill-up-your-hard-drive.html) on the system drive because the log archive process will run repeatedly, generating hundreds of 128 MB temp files which eventually fill up the drive. (If this ever happens to you, this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/944069/213131) explains how to fix the problem.)